# RESET Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, angular8

Actually i use Google Places Autocomplete  in my form and when i want to reset my form , all the fields are set to null but the Google Places Autocomplete cannot be seted to null .

Answer (score 0):

don't reset the autocomplete field.